# Rails 3.1 and sprockets make it harder to debug using firebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

In Rails 3.1, [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/) are used to manage assets and package them into a single file. Which, in general, is not such a bad idea.

As quoted from an external source, which explains the issue at hand:

> A problem with this approach is that
>   it could make debugging harder, if you
>   have to look at the "concatenated" CSS
>   file in production to make sense of
>   what code's included and not, it's
>   harder to know what comes from where
>   than if you just included the original
>   source code files.
>
> One solution would be to have a way to
>   switch between "concatenated" and
>   "normal" modes easily (maybe it's
>   already possible, I don't know), so
>   that normal development would be
>   unimpeded. But you'd have to resort to
>   the big concatenated file for
>   debugging in production.

In Rails 3.0.X, our designer could easily pin-point the CSS setting using Firebug, which will indicate the file and line number directly, since all CSS files were separate and not packaged into one.

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Deleted my answer, went back and look at a Rails 3.1 app I have, the files are concatenated in development, just not compressed. Looking at the source there is no flag to disable this behaviour. Perhaps this might be something that is worth creating a ticket for on Rails' Github Issues. I had a quick search and couldn't see anything similar.

Comment: Actually, since Rails 3.1 expects my default that you should be using SCSS and CoffeeScript, the outputted files are not going to be the same as the source anyway. I remember seeing talk of someone creating a Firebug plugin for SCSS and coffeescript, was a few weeks back though.

Comment: I do think it's an issue. I've seen Jammit suggested as an alternative to Sprockets because Jammit serves up separate files in development.

Comment: Hi Douglas. Came across a plugin called Firesass. I think this is what you were intending. On a side-note, Would be nice if Rails 3.1 natively gives the option to not concatenate files in dev mode, to make debugging easier in the development stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in the end (when the RC gets closer/becomes a release) you will be able to modify your `config/application.rb` with the following
    config.assets.css_compressor = false

But, atm, that doesn't really fix it since the stylesheet_asset_tag helper function isn't exactly compatible with the new pipeline and the :all modifier doesn't work, so...

In your `application.html.erb` view you will have to link each css

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheets/application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheets/foo" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheets/bar" %>
```

As long as you have `config.assets.enabled = true` in your `config/application.rb` the root of assets will be (by default) `/assets`

You can fire up a rails console (`rails c`) and `p Rails.application.assets` to see the properties that are configurable in the mean time.

I agree not the best solution, but at this point (using an RC vs a stable release) its the best way I've found.

**UPDATE:**  Digging around the edge api, found this ActionView::Helper `sprockets_stylesheet_link_tag`  (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SprocketsHelper.html) but it seems to be still an incomplete replacement for stylesheet_link_tag since it doesn't support `:all` and you still have to have the `stylesheets/` segment in your function call. With that said, its prolly the function to use moving forward, so...

```
<%= sprockets_stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheets/foo" %>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
```

The files will not be concatenated in development but will in other environments.

Answer (score 5):

Add ?debug_assets=true to any URL you want to debug. It splits the assets into their parts. Without it, concatenation happens according to your environment settings.

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution to debug assets, actually it's what I do, instead of modifying layout file (and commit the debug symbol accidentally) I prefer using the debug option in the URL which makes more sense and much faster

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :debug =>true%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :debug => true %>
```

It Will gives you following output in view source of your browser

```
 <link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Pushing this to production will likely break things. Better to use @Sucrenoir's approach above which effectively sets debug to true only while developing.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting issue. If I precompile assets (to commit into git), test in production mode, and then go back to using a development environment on the same machine, I see this problem.

Even though I'm back in development mode, the contents of public/assets are being cached and served instead of fresh asset contents. So here's how I fixed it:

```
rm -rf public/assets
```

Answer (score 0):

sprockets probably will work only in production environment, there's no need to package everything into a single file during development and test